# Swift - Object instantiation in Test class

Tags: unit-testing, swift, xctest, objectinstantiation

I am trying to test a class I have written. I have added a new test target and in there I have imported the target of the class I am trying to test. My code looks like this:

```
import XCTest
import TargetContainingClass

class Tests: XCTestCase
{
   var myClass = MyClass()

   // tests

}
```

However, I get the error:

```
'MyClass' is not constructible with '()'
```

`MyClass` does not contain an `init()` method so does not need to be constructed with anything. I therefore don't understand the error I am getting.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What is the definition of your MyClass?

Comment: It just has a bunch of functions. No instance variables or anything.

Comment: I've just tested this in beta 4, with a test case, exactly as you've described, and it worked fine, no compile errors. My MyClass was defined as `class MyClass { func testFunc() { println("This is testFunc") } }`. Either we need to see your code to figure out what's going on, or you're using an old beta.

Comment: Ah! Looks like it might be related to access control. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/1013522#1013522 (Though that doesn't explain why it works for me...) Try manually adding a default constructor: just `init() {}` looks like it should work to make the initialiser public.

Comment: The suggestions in the thread you linked to are that the `init()` needs to be made public. This solves the issue I posted about, but gives me new errors, as I've mentioned in the comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an implementation of `init()` as:

```
class MyClass {
  init () {}
}
```

The Swift documentation states:

```
“Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or base class that provides 
 default values for all of its properties and does not provide at least one initializer
 itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of 
 its properties set to their default values.”  
    Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.”
```

But the above is apparently not true; in action:

```
  1> class MyClass1 {}
  2> MyClass1()
/var/folders/.../expr.DO8uJ4.swift:2:1: error: 'MyClass1' is not constructible with '()'
MyClass1()
^
  2> class MyClass { 
  3.     init () {} 
  4. }    
  5> MyClass()
$R0: __lldb_expr_3.MyClass = {}
```

Comment: Hmm yes I didn't think `init() { }` was needed if nothing was being initialised? Adding `init() { }` gets rid of those errors but gives me `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error`. I know without seeing everything it's hard to say, but any initial thoughts?

Comment: What Xcode6 beta are you using?  I just checked in Beta4 and `init()` is not needed; and my trivial test target links and runs.

Comment: Aha. That only happens in the repl, and also potentially in test cases as in the OP's case, because of [a problem introduced with the access controls](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1013522#1013522) that makes a default init() inaccessible.

Comment: I'm using Beta4. If `init()` isn't needed, what could the source of my error be then?

Comment: Yup, I was wrong. The problem does exist in beta 4. I'll see if I can reproduce your linker error in a minute.

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in the REPL (reported) that fails to correctly namespace classes (and structs) and fails to tie them together. If you  paste in the entire content it works; and if you put the class definition on the same line as the use case, it works as well. Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> class MyClass{}; MyClass()
$R0: __lldb_expr_1.MyClass = {}

Comment: @gcjensen Sorry, was pulled away. The only way I've found of getting it to work was to expose both the class and its init method as public. i.e. `public class MyClass { ... public init() {} ... }`. This article on Medium looks like a good exploration of the current state of affairs, and offers another workaround, that of adding the class under test as a compile target of the test project, so the methods don't have to be fully public.

Comment: Ooop: The link would help, wouldn't it? https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-testing-privates-or-rather-internals-9a3ac5a8a501

Comment: @MattGibson No problem! Exposing both the class and the init method as public gets rid of my initial error but gives me the `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error`'s I previously mentioned. Any thoughts on these?

Comment: @AlBlue So are you saying that would be the cause of my `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error`s? If one of my classes is a test class neither of those solutions would work though, would they?

Comment: @gcjensen Nope, I can't see them here. I can successfully run a test call of a (trivial) function with the class and initialiser public (in beta 4.) Have you re-tried with beta 5? I've not tested this case in 5 yet.

Comment: @MattGibson I've not been able to download beta 5 yet. I'll try it with that later and see what happens.

Comment: @MattGibson I'm still getting the same `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error` in Beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue firstly by providing an implementation of `init() {}` as suggested by @GoZoner, then to get rid of the `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error` I had to add the class I wanted to test as a Compile Source in the build phases.